# Macros: Recorded Macro not working

Tags: excel, vba

I have recorded a macro in excel using `Record Macro option`. However, when I run it, I get the `Error 438` and the error box displays `Object does not support property or method`. Here is the generated macro code. Can someone explain here:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    ActiveCell.Range("A1:C1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'Sheet2'!$A$4:$C$4")
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlPie
    Application.CutCopyMode = True
    Selection.Cut
    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
```

When I debug, I get the error in `Selection.Cut`. I am wondering how come a recorded macro generated not working code

Comment: [INTERESTING READ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select)

Answer (score 0):

Though not a good way,

but changing `Selection.Cut` to `Selection.Parent.Parent.Cut` should work.

And remember, avoid using `Select` whenever possible

Answer (score 0):

Slightly polished version (using references and avoiding selection) that should work:

```
Sub Macro1()
' Macro1 Macro
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = ActiveSheet   ' This is likely 'Sheet 1'
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ActiveCell.Range("A1:C1")
    Dim shp As Shape
    Set shp = ws1.Shapes.AddChart
    shp.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'Sheet2'!$A$4:$C$4")
    shp.Chart.ChartType = xlPie
    Application.CutCopyMode = True
    shp.Cut
    Sheets("Sheet3").Paste
    Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    ws2.Activate
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```